# how to transfer textbox value from app inventor to google sheet web app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, query-string, app-inventor

i have created a google web app,
when i am typing a number in the orders textbox,
i'm getting a match result in the disabled amount textbox,
from the google sheet column,
the web app working good

now,what i want to do is to be able to create a textbox in app inventor
and when put an orders value and clicking a button
i will get the amount result on a label on the app invenotr interface

its not working on app inventor

here is the code i made in app inventor
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**this the Code.gs**

```js
function doGet(e) {
  
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page');

}



function getCost(oneCode){
  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyX";
  va
  return "not found";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("change", doThis);
  });

  function doThis() {
    var oneCode = document.getElementById("one").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateAmount).getCost(oneCode);
  }

  function updateAmount(cost) {
    document.getElementById("two").value = cost;
  }
</script>

<body>
  <div>
    <input id="one" type="text">
    <label for="one">orders</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input disabled id="two" type="text">
    <label for="two">amount</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: we app]

[image: google sheet]

Comment: I’ve never used app inventor but your deGet(e) is not utilizing any of it’s event object nor is it returning anything to the web app

Comment: In the end if you want our help then you need to create a [mcve] that we can run from Google Apps Script Editor to reproduce the problem.  Having any expectation that we will utilize App Inventor to debug you code will most likely not be realized

Comment: @Cooper i've edit my question and attached the code example

Comment: Query Any Google Sheet with a Web App from App Inventor:
https://ai2.metricrat.co.uk/guides/query-any-google-sheet-with-a-web-app

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function doThis() {
    var oneCode = document.getElementById("one").value;
    console.log(oneCode);
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateAmount).getCost(oneCode);
  }
```

and this:

```
function getCost(oneCode){
  console.log('onecode');
  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyXX6axO9G9ANDW0LaQVgezT6hSzSld8CRt2VbsZV6v8XXwNus/exec";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  var ordersList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0].toString(); });
  var amountList = data.map(function(r){ return r[1].toString(); });
  var position = ordersList.indexOf(oneCode);
  if(position > -1){
    return amountList[position];
  }
  return "not found";
}
```

And then run the code and goto View/Executions and see where you losing the data.

Comment: i run the code with the changes you mention,i viewed the Execution and saw that when i'm define function doGet(e) { return getCost(e); } its showes the "head" and the name of the parameter that set in the function,it seem that app script passing the value if i i'm not wrong,i think i understand my problem,my question is how do i set my input value on app invertor on google app script int the function getCost instead of (oneCode) i want to set the input value tha coming from App invertor

Comment: As I said I've never used app inventor and from the looks of it I don't think it's something i would waste my time with.